# Return all negative elements of a array

Tags: java, arrays

Okay, so i need to find all the negative numbers of array and return them.I found the negative number, but how do i return them all? P.S yes i am a beginner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = {5,-1,6,3,-20,10,20,-5,2};
        System.out.println(findNumber(array));
    }




public static int findNumber(int[] sum) {
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length ; i++) {
        if(sum[i] < num) {
            num = sum[i];
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: return as an array... create a new array

Comment: put them into another array (or `ArrayList`) and return that?

Comment: then your method needs to return another array. Read up on ArrayList, and toArray() method.

Comment: i need to keep it as array, not arrayList.....but i am doubting that i understood the exercise wrongly :(

Comment: At the end you can return an array toArray() but since arrays are fixed size you cant decide the of your array. Add negative numbers to an ArrayList and at the end return arrayList.toArray().

Comment: Also keep tracking the last negative number is unnecessary you can always compare just to 0.

Comment: `if(sum[i] < num) {` should be `if(sum[i] < 0) {`

Answer (score 6):

Java 8 based solution. You can use stream to filter out numbers greater than or equal to zero

```
    public static int[] findNumber(int[] sum)
    {
        return Arrays.stream(sum).filter(i -> i < 0).toArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this, if you just want to output all of the negative numbers easily you could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array = {5,-1,6,3,-20,10,20,-5,2};
    ArrayList<Integer> negativeNumbers = findNumber(sum);
    for(Integer negNum : negativeNumbers) {
        System.out.println(negNum);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> findNumber(int[] sum) {
    ArrayList<Integer> negativeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length ; i++) {
        if(sum[i] < 0) {
          negativeNumber.add(sum[i]);
        }
    }
    return negativeNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you told you are beginner, i'm giving code in using arrays only.

Whenever you come across a negative number, just add it to the array and increment it's index number and after checking all the numbers, return the array and print it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] array = {5,-1,6,3,-20,10,20,-5,2};
    int[] neg = findNumber(array);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<neg.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(neg[i]);
    }
}

public static int[] findNumber(int[] a)
{
    int j=0;
    int[] n = new int[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] <0)
        {
            n[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    int[] neg = new int[j];
    for( int k = 0 ; k < j ; k++)
    {
        neg[k] = n[k];
    }

    return neg;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Correct, but your result may be a vector without a single negative number. Am I right?

Comment: @MiguelKVidal yeah. The returned array may be empty according to the passed array. Is that want you meant?

Comment: You could copy neg to a j length array and you wont return array with possible empty places.

Comment: What I meant: your array may be full of zeroes..
`int[] v = new int[10];` is equivalent to `int[] v = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`

Comment: I saw it... Now your answer is correct and complete! :)

Answer (score 0):

You code is returning the sum of elements, but I understood that you wanted every negative number.
So, I assumed you want something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [] array = {5,-1,6,3,-20,10,20,-5,2};
  Integer [] result = findNumbers( array );
  for( int i : result )
  {
    System.out.println( i );
  }
}
public static Integer[] findNumbers(int[] v) {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < v.length ; i++) {
      if(v[i] < 0) {
          list.add(v[i]);
      }
  }
  return list.toArray( new Integer[0] );
}
```

Is it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your method to iterate through the array of numbers, and add every negative number you encounter, to a List.

```
public static List<Integers> findNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
    List<Integers> negativeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if(num[i] < 0) {
            negativeNumbers.add(num[i]);
        }
    }
    return negativeNumbers;
}
```

You could then print out the list of negative numbers from this method itself, or return the list with `return` to be printed in main.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] findNum(int[] array)
{
    int negativeIntCount = 0;
    int[] negativeNumbers = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < 0)
        {
            negativeIntCount++;
            negativeNumbers[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total negative numbers in given arrays is " + negativeIntCount);

    return negativeNumbers;
}
```

To display as an array in output :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findNum(array)));
```

To display output as space gaped integers :

```
for(int x : findNum(array))
{
    System.out.print(" " + x)
}
```